Analyses of Associations and Predictive Models in Random Forest
I am studying how Random Forests work to use this methodology in investigating the most important variables associated with a specific blood-based biomarker.
I would like some help to determine if my understanding below is correct.
If I want to create a predictive model, then I understand that I should use a training set (for example, 70%) and a test set (30%). On the other hand, if I only want to analyze the main variables associated with the biomarker, then there is no need to split the data into training and test sets.
Is my interpretation correct?


If I want to create a predictive model, then I understand that I should use a training set (for example, 70%) and a test set (30%). On the other hand, if I only want to analyze the main variables associated with the biomarker, then there is no need to split the data into training and test sets.

I disagree. Some will say this for linear modeling (which has its own set of caveats),$^{\dagger}$ but that is because there is a more-or-less straightforward way to penalize model complexity through adjusted $R^2$. In a random forest, there is not as straightforward of a way to calculate, in-sample, what the error variance is and how it compares to overall variance, while considering model complexity. This is typically assessed using some kind of out-of-sample measure of performance on data that the trained model has not yet seen.
Ditto for neural networks, support vector regressions, etc.
$^{\dagger}$One caveat that comes to mind is that, if you use regularized regression (e.g., ridge, LASSO, or elastic net) or use cross-validation to tune the number of spline knots in your model, you no longer have that nice unbiased variance estimator for calculating the adjusted $R^2$.
